# The inverse of a linear operator in a transformation's vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

**Let** $\mathbf S$ be some group of vectors.

**Let** $\mathbf V$ be the vector space of all the functions  $f:S \to F $

**Let** $\mathtt g: S \to S$.

**Let** $\mathtt T$ be a linear operator $V\to V$ defined by: $(Tf)(s) = (f \circ g)(s)$.

**Prove** that $T$ is reversible if and only if $g$ is reversible, and find in this case the inverse of $T$.

I have tried to find a way to prove that $Ker(T)=\langle0\rangle$, or $Ker(g)=\langle0\rangle$, with no luck. Can't think of any algebraic manipulation to prove this one...

Comment: I've edited your post because $Tf$ (the image of $f$ by $T$) **isn't** $T\circ f$.

Comment: im unsure what "the image of $f$ by $T$ means...

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29#Notation.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the inverse if $T$ will be
$$T^{-1}f = f\circ g^{-1}.$$

Comment: I know - a simple sketch of the problem shows me that. But still, how can I prove it?

Comment: @YonatanIzutskiver, what happens if $Tf = 0\implies  f =0$?

Comment: @YonatanIzutskiver: Suppose that $g$ is reversible and calculate $f \circ g^{-1} \circ g$ as well as $f \circ g \circ g^{-1}$. How can you formulate this in terms of $T$ and $S(\cdot) = \cdot \circ g^{-1}$?